# open source firmware and router that support at least a dozen of simultaneous connections

Tags: wireless-networking

My family has ten persons. Each of us owns one or two devices that try to connect to the Internet.

We regularly have problems where the router drops the connection to ISP. I begin to suspect that this is happening when too many devices are connected simultaneously.

Does that make sense ? Would I get better support if I use a router supported by open source firmware ? Which firmware would support best that amount of connections ?

Comment: More than 10 devices on a access point ? Forget it. Tell your family to use a cable, especially if your neighborhood is also using Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 2):

More then 10 devices per access point is quite possible, but most SOHO devices can have a hard time with it. Especially if it needs to remember a lot of states (e.g. when someone uses torrents, or when someone starts WoW and it updates itself).

Having said that:

1. Enterprise level devices often work fine with ~ 50 connections per access point. So it is possible. Those usually use 'beefier' hardware though.
2. You could do some testing. What happens if you connect most of them via a cable and turn off wireless. If the connection still drops then the problem is not the wireless part.
3. If it turns out to be the wireless part, then run something like inSSIder, see which channels are use and which method. Then add that to the post. (E.g. all devices on wireless-B/G/N at 2.4 GHz? Or Do things use wireless-N at 5 GHz. Wide or narrow band on the 2.4 Part? Which channels are in use with the neighbours? Do the conenction drop when someone turns on Bluetooth (same frequence) or uses a Electromagnetic radiation bombardment chamber?

[image]

(Also known as a microwave).

---

Added after reading your comment.

> However, my issue is with the router dropping its connection to ISP rather 
>   than a wifi issue. (I just edited the question to make it less misleading.)

In that case I see these potential problem points:

1. The link between your router and the ISP
2. The router itself. (Quality)
3. The router itself. (Memory)

The link between your router and the ISP:
This falls outside my scope of knowledge. If you have a poor link and you start heavily using it problems may occur. That assumes a lot. E.g. that you have some sort of DSL. And it is not something you can fix.

The router itself. (Quality):
The current router might not be made well and might be part of the same problem at point 1. New firmware etc is not likely to solve anything. Replacing the router will. (Borrowing an other router and testing with that might indicate if this is the problem or if it is something else).

The router itself. (Memory):
More active users (at the same time) means that the router was to remember more details. While attempting to do that it may run out of memory. Another firmware on the router will have the same problems, but if you install DD-WRT or similar you can log in on the router and you can see how much memory is free and and how much is in use.

If that is the case one solution is a router with more memory.  Either from s shop or home-build.  (@Florenz Kley mentions Soekris Engineering. Those things are really great for building own solutions, but they have a rather high price for mere home usage as router. Of you go that way (or PC engines or similar) then you probably want to make it both router, access point and NAS).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. However, my issue is with the router dropping its connection to ISP rather than a wifi issue. (I just edited the question to make it less misleading.)

Answer (score 0):

Usee [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org) with a small embedded system, like [PC Engines](http://www.pcengines.ch) or [Soekris](http://www.soekris.com). I have  been using a Soekris net4501 for 6 years now, this machine gives me the least trouble of all computers I maintain, supporting 6 nodes and ~ 5 WiFi devices.

Answer (score 0):

A router with DD-WRT should be able to handle 20+ clients without a problem, so find something which supports 802.11n, 300gig throughput and a reasonable CPU [for an AP/router] and locate it strategically.

While there is no doubt some difference in capability between DD-WRT, OpenWRT and Tomato, this will probably be minor as they are all based on Linux.

I'm not giving this as advice, but I recently attended a Network Operators Group, and the names Mikrotic and Ubiquity came up regularly as particularly solid gear.  (I've not tried one though but Mikrotic did bribe us by providing free routers, so this may also not be entirely unbiased.)

Comment: I tried to find which ADSL routers can run one of the firmwares you mentioned but did not find that much information. Would you have any suggestion ?

Comment: DD-WRT supported devices list: http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices      Tomatoe supporter devices list: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tomato_Firmware/Supported_Devices (including a WNR3500 in both lists)

Comment: You may want to look at a cheap/dumb ADSL modem and hook it up to a Wireless router - I don't think Tomato / *wrt support for ADSL is that good, if it exists at all.